# Jquery show method doesn't work in my rails project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery-ui

I have the following code in create.js.erb (called via ajax whenever an item is added to the cart)

```
$('#cart').show('blind', 1000);

$('#cart').html("<%= j render @cart %>")

$('#current_item').css({'background-color':'#88ff88'}).animate({'background-color':'#114411'}, 1000)
```

The show method doesnt work. The animate method works just fine. The snippet is exactly the same as it is in the book (Agile Web Development with Rails 4e)

The following is the car partial that render calls, _cart.html.erb

```
<div class="cart_title">Your Cart <%= "is Empty.." if !cart.line_items.any? %></div>
<% unless cart.line_items.empty? %>
<table>
  <%= render cart.line_items %>
  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<%= button_to 'Empty Cart', cart, method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?' %>
<p><%= link_to 'Back to Store', store_path %></p>
<% end %>
```

With the jquery code, everytime a new element is added to the cart, the cart should execute show's behaviour.. But it doesnt. the .html and .css calls work just fine, as well as the animate function.

Comment: Are you sure `jquery-ui.js` is included? What do you see in js console, any error?

Comment: I dont know how to access the js console... I installed Node.js as a requirement for my rails environment. It is included because all the other calls work. I believe the animate functions is a jquery supplied function. I get no Sprokets errors either.

Comment: Can you try to set up a [jsfiddle](http:/www.jsfiddle.net)? You can access the Console in your browser. Just load your page and press F12. A window should pop up